# MVC4 sending an xml string and reading it in javascript make my js function undefined

Tags: javascript, xml, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to load a tree view, in MVC4 view, by sending an xml (not that big ~30 "screen size lines").
Actually I fill it in my controller as a simple text string. Which is ok.

I fill a variable in js by

```
function buildTree() {
       debugger
       var s_s = @ViewBag.xml;
        tree.setImagePath("../../Scripts/dhtmlxTree/imgs/csh_bluebooks/");
        tree.enableDragAndDrop(true);
        tree.setSkin("dhx_skyblue");
    }
```

This changes my '<', newlines ... to &dl, &dt etc... 
But when debugging the string s_s looks ok otherwise.

The problem is that I get an undefined error in javascript on my main js function that calls the buildTree(), that would otherwise go away when I comment

```
// var s_s = @ViewBag.xml;
```

**I did some adidtional troubleshooting - and the issue is not even at the js in the view, where youread viewbag.xml. Actually as soon as you assign it in the conroller the js error would appear. Although it is a simple formatted string with relatively modest size.**
Help please, many thanks

OK - I think my problem is really related to newline and newspace being sent in a string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may just need to quote the XML:

```
var s_s = '@ViewBag.xml';
```

Comment: thanks harriyott - that did not do it - but i added some more info please see the original post